# Spark unresolved dependencies hadoop

Tags: sbt, apache-spark

I tried to build [self-contained example scala application](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/quick-start.html), but when running `sbt package` I get the following:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-common;1.0.4: not found
[warn]  :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-client;1.0.4: not found
[warn]  :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-api;1.0.4: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] {file:/home/niko/workspace/Spark/recommender/}default-3ebb80/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-common;1.0.4: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-client;1.0.4: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-api;1.0.4: not found
```

Does anyone know what has to be configured in order to run the app successfully (if possible without hadoop installed)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because your sbt fails to retrieve target file, the URL for repos is not unavailable.

Download the latest sbt version, and add the following to `~/.sbt/repositories`:

```
[repositories]
  local
  sbt-releases-repo: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  sbt-plugins-repo: http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  maven-central: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
```

Answer (score 1):

You enabled the YARN profile, but did not set `hadoop.version`. The default Hadoop version is 1.0.4, and there is no such YARN. In general you want to specify `hadoop.version` no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem when trying to get my spark program to build. I found out that my version of sbt was giving me the errors. I would recommend completely removing sbt. Then download it from here http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html. Download the .tgz. Extract it to your home folder. Then add the bin directory to your path.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by enabling the auto-import option and then compiling it again